# Fingerprint reader driver thinkpad T480s

Tags: drivers, thinkpad

Is there any driver for Thinkpad T480s fingerprint reader?
I have already tried Figerprint GUI and fprint-demo but without succes.

Comment: have you had any luck with this? Same problem here. Found this guide, which I followed, but reader is still not found with Fingerprint GUI: https://launchpad.net/~3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/libfprint-vfs0090

Comment: I didn't manage to install it.                                                                                        
`❯ sudo validity-sensors-tools.led-test
Unable to access to USB devices
 validity-sensors-tools is installed as a snap.
 To allow it to function correctly you may need to run:
   sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:raw-usb
   sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:hardware-observe
`

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint reader for the T480s will work in eOS6, as it has a newer kernel that supports it. You *may* need to install the Python Validity interface, though.

If you're running eOS6 (or have a kernel that is 5.4.x or newer), try this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. List your USB devices:

   ```
   sudo lsusb
   ```
2. Look for the fingerprint reader, which may look something like:

   ```
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. Metallica MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
   ```
3. If you already have the basic PAM Validity driver installed, try to enrol a finger:

   ```
   fprintd-enroll
   ```

   If this comes back with an error, install [the Python Validity drivers](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity):

   ```
   sudo apt remove fprintd
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
   ```

   Once everything has finished installing, try to enrol a finger:

   ```
   fprintd-enroll
   ```

This has been successfully configured on four Lenovo ThinkPad T480s notebooks (Japanese model) running Elementary OS 6